# Parse - unable to send notifications (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I'm attempting to send notifications to my via via Back4App.com which is a parse backend server, but nothing is being sent and I'm not sure why.

Everything was working fine, when I first implemented it - but now that I have rolled out the current app version to TestFlight I am no longer able to send notifications from the dashboard - getting the following error: stream ended unexpectedly.

I have tried recreating and re-uploading both the development and production push certificates but still having the same issue. I've also tested on a APNs service which is sending notifications as expected.

Any ideas what I could have missed here?

Comment: Usually, it is related to the export procedure of the iOS certificate. It just worked by selecting the certificate under "My certificates" on Keychain App and exporting it as p12 file. Exporting the certificate from another folder different from "my certificates" will result on this error. Can you check if you're doing that as they recommend in their docs?

Comment: Getting the exact same error with TestFlight. Have you figured this out?